# Object-Oriented Design: Which is better practice?

Tags: java, oop, class, interface

I have a confusion in different ways the objects are created which I have seen in java docs and other programming books. For e.g.

Assuming there is a `base class` and a `derived class`

1- I have a variable of type `Base` which refers to the object of type `Derived`

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2- I have a variable of type `Derived` which refers to the object of type `Derived`

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

My question is what should be my thinking while choosing between 1 and 2? Is it to take advantage of `Polymorphism` in general Base-Derived scenarios?

Is there a `better practice` while choosing between 1 and 2 that I am not aware of or is it just a `personal decision`?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, List is an interface.
**Another question**: Will my decision change if I use a Type parameter?

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

**Update Answer:** This is actually called `"Programming to the interface"`. Thanks Code-Guru. Exactly what I was looking for is explained in very simple terms in one of the answers to this question - [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Comment: Option 1 is typically preferred (ignoring the difference between an abstract base class and an interface). In OOP, we call this "programming to the interface".

Comment: Sorry about that. Please see another question, edited.

Comment: I still suggest that you declare `list` as `List<T>` rather than `ArrayList<T>`. Changing to a type parameter doesn't significantly change your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `List` is not a base class it is an `interface` and therefore **should** be used wherever possible.

   Using the interface that a class implements allows you to work with all classes that implement the interface, not just the specific class.
2. `String` is a concrete class so it is much clearer to use it directly.

   Sometimes, however, even though `String` implements the `CharSequence` interface it is unnecessary to use `CharSequence` because it would just be confusing. However, take a look at `StringBuilder`, it uses `CharSequence` almost exclusively.

In summary - there is no **better** there is just **appropriate**.

Comment: So 1 is preferable but when is it appropriate to use case 2? Please see my another question, edited.

Comment: @Prince - It is appropriate to use `String` when `CharSequence` would merely complicate.

Comment: I do not understand your explanation for `2`. When will it be confusing? When should I work with just the `ArrayList` class?

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Actually found a nice explanation here - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3):

Choosing the base type allows you to at some point in the future change between using an ArrayList to say a LinkedList, without changing the rest of the code. This gives you more flexibility to refactor later on. Likewise, your public methods should return a List instead of the specific type of List implementation for the same reason -- so that you may change your internal implementation to optimize performance without breaking the contract to your callers.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where List is a class ( just assume for the purpose of answering your question -  **"Shall we use object of Parent class representing child class or use object of type derived class ( actula class) ? "**

1) You were correct, its solely for the purpose of polymorphism.

2) Mostly its used for Passing the object around different class methods. Other classes' methods may be accepting parent class a input. you have to use the casting in those places.